# Failed to load plugin libhector_gazebo_ros_gps.so

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

While launching Summit XL robot launch file, I am getting this execution error.
Please help to solve this, Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259386/failed-to-load-plugin-libhector_gazebo_ros_gps.so/) by [Waleed_Shahzaib](https://answers.ros.org/users/28961/waleed_shahzaib/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2017-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I meet the same problem.
I fixed it by `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-hector-gazebo-plugins`.

---

Originally posted by [taiping.z](https://answers.ros.org/users/26425/taiping.z/) with karma: 16 on 2018-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0